# JPA connecting to wrong table

Tags: java, jpa, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am trying to learn JPA
Here is my entity file.
Passenger.java

```
@Entity

public class Passenger implements Serializable{
public Passenger() {
    super();
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

}
```

My persistence.xml is below.

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.1">
 <persistence-unit name="JPA_POJO">
     <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/airlines</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.airline.model.Passenger</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

My servlet is like this.

```
@WebServlet(name = "addPassenger")
public class addPassenger extends HttpServlet {
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Passenger p = new Passenger();
//        airline p = new airline();

    p.setFirstName("ABC");
    p.setLastName("XYZ");

    EntityManagerFactory emf =       Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPA_POJO");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(p);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

}
```

}

When I run this code I get the following error.

> org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'airline.passenger' doesn't exist
>   Error Code: 1146
>   Call: INSERT INTO PASSENGER (ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?)

As far as I can understand it is trying to connect to PASSENGER table instead of AIRLINE table.
I have assigned the data source that points to airline table. In fact I wrote a class file airline.java basically same as Passenger.java, when I used airline.java object(commented out in code) in my servlet it worked.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it does seem to be totally expected, you did not provide a name to the table of your entity `Passenger` so it uses the name of the entity as default table name so it tries to insert into the table `Passenger` of the schema `airline` which is what is expected.

For me your problem is only that the table has not been created so far, if you want let `eclipselink` create your table for you, you should add the property `eclipselink.ddl-generation` to your file `persistence.xml` and set it to `create-or-extend-tables` as described [here](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_ddl_generation.htm).

In your case it will be something like:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="JPA_POJO">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/airlines</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.airline.model.Passenger</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jtaDataSource" value="java:/airlines"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: I updated the xml
Now it gives the following error.
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4021] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Unable to acquire a connection from driver [null], user [null] and URL [null].  Verify that you have set the expected driver class and URL.  Check your login, persistence.xml or sessions.xml resource.  The jdbc.driver property should be set to a class that is compatible with your database platform

Comment: Is there a way to make Passenger.java write to airline table?

Comment: add @Table(name = "AIRLINE") after @Entity

Comment: Thanks a lot.
New persistence.xml worked and also @Table worked.